# Attaching multiple files using bash and emailing it out using SWAKS or another program

Tags: email, for, sendmail, mailx

I'm trying to:

1. Attach multiple files into one email.
2. Have the email sent out using a Gmail account with the current date and time in the subject header.

I'm having trouble with the for a loop since I don't want to create multiple emails **I just one to create one email with all the attachments included** and **have the current date and time used in the subject line**.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# to run type "bash email_live_listing.sh"

dt_now_start=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"`
fn_dt_now_start=`date '+%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S'`; #use to generate file name with date
currentdir="$(pwd)" #get current directory


ls $currentdir/us*.pdf -tp | grep -v '/$fn_pdf' #place files into variable

echo "$fn_pdf"

ITER=0
for t in ${fn_pdf[@]}; do
swaks --to to@gmail.com -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -tls -au from@gmail.com -ap password --header "Subject: Updated file ${fn_dt_now_start}" --body "Email Text" --attach-type ./${fn_pdf} -S 2
let ITER+=1 #increment number
done
```

Ps: I'm using Ubuntu and **Swaks** since it's compact and lightweight, and **will be run from a raspberry pi**, but I'm willing to try other options.

Comment: `swaks` can take multiple `--attach-type` options. So in the for loop, add those to a variable, then call `swaks` once with this variable in addition to the one-time options. Be careful with the quoting.

Comment: @dirkt that's great but I'm not sure how to do that do you have a link to an example?

Comment: You don't assign `$fn_pdf`, also `dt_now_start`, `t'  looks unsued. Better practice would be using ``$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T")`` instead ``date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bash script that might help others out that I got to work.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    currentdir="$(pwd)" #get current directory
    fn_dt_now_start=`date '+%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S'`; #use to generate date time

    fn_txt=$(ls $currentdir/*.txt) #place txt files found into a variable

    for t in ${fn_txt[@]}; do
        attach_files="${attach_files} --attach-type ${t}" #will build list of files to attach
    done

    swaks --to email_going_to@gmail.com -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -tls -au email_sending_from@gmail.com -ap <email_sending_from_password>] --header "Subject: Listings - ${fn_dt_now_start}" --body "Listings Email Text" ${attach_files} -S 2
```